My nextJs app is not picking up environment variables from .env.local file. How can I fix that in localhost
I have an application in nextJs. I am using nextAuth for authentication with firebase methods. Now google 0Auth is implemented form the client side but signInwithcredentials and other methods are implemented in server side as nextAuth authenticates from server side. Now if i paster all the keys for connecting to firebase directly in firebaseConfig, It works fine but if I paste them in .env.local I get an error 'Invalid api-key'. Can someone help fix this for me.
here is my code:
This is my .env.local file:
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY=AIkeffkjn-2429434, -> some value
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN=some value,
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID=some value,
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET=some value,
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=some value,
NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID=some value
NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=some value
BASEPATH=http://localhost:3000
NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_URL=http://localhost:3000

this is my firebaseApp.ts in configs directory:
import { initializeApp } from '@firebase/app'
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider } from '@firebase/auth'
const app = initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: 'some value',
  projectId: 'some value',
  storageBucket: 'some value',
  messagingSenderId: 'some value',
  appId: 'some value'
})

export const auth = getAuth(app)
export const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
export default app

Now for reference if you need my nextAuth code:
// nextAuth providers
import CredentialProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import type { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import useAuthService from '@/services/AuthService'
const { login, register, googleAuth, updatePass } = useAuthService()

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      type: 'credentials',
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials) {
        const { email, password, action, rememberme, username, User, oobCode } = credentials as {
          email: string
          password: string
          action: string
          rememberme?: boolean
          username?: string
          User?: any
          oobCode: string
        }
        try {
          if (action === 'register' && register) {
            const user = await register(email, password, username)
            return user
          } else if (action === 'login' && login) {
            const user = await login({ email, password, rememberme })
            return user
          } else if (action === 'google' && googleAuth) {
            console.log('google action triggered')
            const user = typeof User === 'string' ? JSON.parse(User) : User
            console.log('user in google action: ', user)
            return user
          }
        } catch (e: any) {
          console.log('there was an error fetching details: ', e.message)
          throw new Error(e.message)
        }
        return null
      }
    })
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 // ** 30 days
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login'
  },

  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        ;(token['uid'] = user.uid),
          (token.email = user.email),
          (token.displayName = user.displayName),
          (token['photoURL'] = user.photoURL),
          (token['emailVerified'] = user.emailVerified)
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.name = token.displayName as string | null | undefined
        session.user.email = token.email
        session.user.image = token.photoURL as string | null | undefined
      }
      return session
    }
  }
}

this is how I am calling serverside methods:
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormData> = async (data: FormData) => {
    setLoading(true)
    const res = await signIn('credentials', {
      email: data.email,
      password: data.password,
      rememberme: rememberme,
      action: 'login',
      redirect: false
    })
    if (res && res.ok && res.error === null) {
      setLoading(false)
      // Vars
      toast.success('Login successful, redirecting you')
      router.push('/home')
    } else if (res?.error) {
      setLoading(false)
      errorHandler(res?.error)
    }

and this is how I am managing client side methods like 0Auth:
const handleGoogleAuth = async () => {
    if (googleAuth) {
      const user = await googleAuth()
      console.log('user in registration google is: ', user)
      if (user) {
        const userString = JSON.stringify(user)
        const res = await signIn('credentials', {
          action: 'google',
          redirect: false,
          User: userString
        })
        console.log('res is in googleAuth: ', res)
        if (res && res.ok && res.error === null) {
          console.log('google register response: ', res)
          router.push('/home')
        } else {
          if (res?.error) {
            // setErrorState(errors)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

The only problem is that my application is not getting environment variables. How to fix that?

Did you restart the server after updating the .env.local file?

Try renaming variables without NEXT_PUBLIC prefix if you tried to access it on server. This prefix will be accessed by browser not server.

Thanks, It has been resolved. I had to move my environment variables to next.config.js.
